# I'm lost trying to setup Node.js for Stripe payment system, boss dropped project on me with dealine

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Quick background: I'm a network and general IT support guy, not a coder. The last time I did anything with Javascipt was about 21 years ago when I was in HS and used a rollover array for the GIF menus on my personal site.

So this week the bosses at my company decided they wanted to take online payments. An IT consultant friend of the CEOs told them to use Stripe and it'd be easy to implement on our site and I got handed the task of implementing it.

Eventually it'll be tied to to our EMR and the EMR folks will take care of that piece eventually. For right now, they just want page where our clients can enter the amount they want to pay. Yes, I know I could make my life easy and just grab a WP plug-in, but for various reasons we don't want to do that.

As such, I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://stripe.com/docs/accepting-donations#install) as a template to work off of.

The server is CentOS 7 / Node 10.22.1 / PHP 7.3.22 / Apache 2.4.6

So the first hurdle I hit was not having a *package.json*, I used `install init` to create one, but had no clue what to enter for values, so I left them all default/blank.

Then when I ran `npm install stripe` I got this as a result:

```
npm WARN html@1.0.0 No description

npm WARN html@1.0.0 No repository field.

 stripe@8.96.0 updated 1 package and audited 5 packages in 0.82s found 0 vulnerabilities
```

So I went ahead and tried running `node stripe.js` and got this result:

```
/var/www/payment.crisisprepandrecovery.com/html/stripe.js:3
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

So did I not do the first part correctly, does the code actually have bad syntax, Both?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: lets stick with basics, await syntax only works if it is inside a function block that is marked "async" e.g. async function main(){ await stripe.paymentIntents.create }

Comment: Where did you invoke the last command?

npm install stripe will create `node_modules` directory.

You should have your own script that loads stripe as  a dependency

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1477, // $14.77, an easily identifiable amount
      currency: 'usd',
    });
    console.log('Worked! ', paymentIntent.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error! ', err.message);
  }

}

main();
```